# vs code auto generate node server port in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, error-handling, runtime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfSgA.png) why this create file in ubuntu 23.04 lts version

unexpacted i wont to did'nt no shipping-system/server/4000;' (Unknown (FileSystemError): An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.) any one whats the error in this code editor The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to read file '

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557